# C# Lambda expression input param type

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following Unity code -

How does the InjectionFactory constructor at runtime get an actual container instance (c)?

```
container.RegisterType<DbProviderFactory>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
                    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(c.Resolve<IApplicationSettings>().GetValue("DatabaseProviderName"))));
```

For completion, see client class definition below-

```
public static class IocConfig
   { 
        public static void RegisterDependencies(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            IocConfig.container = container;

            container.RegisterType<IApplicationSettings, ConfigAppSettings>();
            container.RegisterType<IViewModelMapper, SimpleRoomViewModelMapper>();
            container.RegisterType<IRoomRepository, AdoNetRoomRepository>();
            container.RegisterType<RepositoryRoomViewModelService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IRoomViewModelReader, RepositoryRoomViewModelService>();
            container.RegisterType<IRoomViewModelWriter, RepositoryRoomViewModelService>();

            container.RegisterType<DbProviderFactory>(new InjectionFactory(c => 
                DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(c.Resolve<IApplicationSettings>().GetValue("DatabaseProviderName"))));
        }

        private static IUnityContainer container;
    }
```

Below is the definition of InjectionFactory-

```
public class InjectionFactory : InjectionMember
    {
        private readonly Func<IUnityContainer, Type, string, object> factoryFunc;

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of <see cref="InjectionFactory"/> with
        /// the given factory function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="factoryFunc">Factory function.</param>
        public InjectionFactory(Func<IUnityContainer, object> factoryFunc)
            : this((c, t, s) => factoryFunc(c))
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of <see cref="InjectionFactory"/> with
        /// the given factory function.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="factoryFunc">Factory function.</param>
        public InjectionFactory(Func<IUnityContainer, Type, string, object> factoryFunc)
        {
            Guard.ArgumentNotNull(factoryFunc, "factoryFunc");
            this.factoryFunc = factoryFunc;
        }
```

Comment: c is a IUnityContainer object and Factory.GetUnitOfWork() returns an object, as specified in the InjectionFactory constructor

Comment: Hi
"c is a IUnityContainer object". How is this inferred?

Comment: Can you show me more code? c should have been declared and assigned before the RegisterType call.

Comment: Hi
Added class defintion above, c is not defined earlier, seems to be inferred?

Comment: `c` will be defined when `factoryFunc` is called in `InjectionFactory`

Comment: But, doesn't factoryfunc need an actual container instance? I am assuming that this instance is supplied by the container instance in the container.RegisterType call; but not sure how that would work? Or am I wrong in my assumption?

Comment: When you instantiate `factoryFunc`, it doesn't need an actual container. Try this example out: `var func = new Func<int, int>(x => 2 * x); Console.WriteLine(func(4));`

Comment: Hi 
Thanks for your reply. I have edited the original question. Now the final piece is how does a container instance get provided to the InjectionFactory instance when it gets created.It does need a IUnityContainer instance.

Comment: I think I have the answer now. container.Resolve is an extension method which passes the container instance all the way up the chain when the constructor of InjectionFactory is called.